# Spring : Place configuration file in Tomcat Lib

Tags: spring, tomcat7

Currently my spring context-web has bean definition :

```
    <bean id="myFile" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
        <constructor-arg value="META-INF/myfile.yml" />
    </bean>
```

Hence, **myfile.yml** I have to keep inside the **war** being deployed. But I want to keep **myfile.yml** in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib folder and refer bean from there.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using tomcat, some specific paths are added to the classpath. You can find them inside `catalina.properties` for the following property:

```
common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar
```

Thus by default `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` is on your classpath, you can simply create your bean like that:

```
<bean id="myFile" class="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource">
    <constructor-arg value="myfile.yml" />
</bean>
```

However you can also use FileSystemResource to retrieve external resources.
Supposing you are using `Spring >= 3`, you can use SpEL language (please refer to the doc [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)) to retrieve system variable.

```
#{systemEnvironment['TOMCAT_HOME']}
```

So the final result looks like:

```
<bean id="myFile" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
    <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['TOMCAT_HOME']}/lib/myfile.yml" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I am getting FileNotFoundException when using it :

Comment: Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [file:/Users/myuser/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/lib/myfile.yml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

Comment: I am using IntellJ 13 .. Do I need to modify anything ?

Comment: My bad i didn't see that you are using ClassPathResource. I don't know this class but I don't think it is possible to load something outside the classpath. We have to find another class.

Comment: I have updated my answer please try with this new class FileSystemResource.

Comment: Using FileSystemResource is not possible as I am using ClassPathResource in many classes for this file. Cant we add TOMCAT_HOME/lib to class path so that no code change are needed ?

Comment: I can't test today I have no dev env, but I will try tomorrow. I think $TOMCAT_HOME/lib is by default in classpath, did you try simply try `value="myfile.yml"`? If not I use Intellij 13 itoo I will try something for tomorrow

Comment: Ok goods, the answer was finally simple but we turn around before finding it :) I will update the answer to reflect the comments we had